# Detect orientation jquery/javascript mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying the following to detect orientation on a mobile device.

On a windows phone it does nothing, and on android it gets caught in what seems like a loop as just alerts all the time.

is there a better way to do this? Maybe with jquery (best option), if not better javascript solution?

```
function doOnOrientationChange () {
  switch (window.orientation) {  
    case -90:
    case 90:
      alert('landscape');
      break; 
    default:
      alert('portrait');
      break; 
  }
}

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doOnOrientationChange);
```

Comment: This article says window.orientation cannot be trusted http://pioul.fr/cross-device-cross-browser-portrait-landscape-detection

Comment: Also interesting seems:https://github.com/borismus/device.js/tree/master and https://github.com/jlubean/orientationchange

Comment: https://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/

Answer (score 3):

Orientation is subject to support and device type.

Here is a very simple crude method you could experiment with that would be widely supported:

```
function doOnOrientationChange () {
  let landscape = ( document.body.clientWidth > document.body.clientHeight );

  alert( landscape ? 'landscape' : 'portrait' )
}


window.addEventListener('resize', doOnOrientationChange);
```

You could add an offset value to change the orientation result to your liking, for example you might want to clamp landscape view on certain screen resolutions that are more square.

Comment: the resize event gets called twice. first with the previous value and then the current orientation value. do you get it as well?

Comment: I have seen a number of event types fire multiple times in all sorts of event bind scenarios, not much you can do about it, If its a problem you could store the last value in a variable when it is changed and then check if the new value is the same, break out of the call if it has not changed like so if(landscape === window.wasLandscape) { return; }